Every diagonalizable matrix is self adjoint
I have to prove the following:
"If $A$ is diagonalizable over $\mathbb{R}$ then there exists an inner product on $\mathbb{R}^n$ such that $A$ is self-adjoint in regards to that inner product."
I thought, I could simply say that $A$ is similar to a diagonal matrix $D$ (via $A = S^{-1}DS$, with $S \in GL_n(K)$ and $D$ being a diagonal matrix). And since $D$ has the eigenvalues of $A$ on its diagonal, and since those are all real, $D$ is self adjoint since $D = D^T$ is true for any diagonal matrix. Thus, I conclude since $A$ is similar to $D$, which is self adjoint, $A$ is also self adjoint. Where is the problem? Because that doesn't seem correct to me since I haven't used any specific inner product.
Thanks in advance!

The problem is that $D=D^T$ doesn't imply $A=A^T$. And clearly not every diagonalizable matrix satisfies this. Self adjoint with respect to an inner product means that $\langle Ax,y\rangle=\langle x, Ay\rangle$ for all $x,y\in\mathbb{R^n}$. This condition is equivalent to $A=A^T$ with the standard inner product, not with any inner product.

that is, there is a symmetric positive definite $H$  such that $HAH^{-1}  = A^T $

fiddle with the formulas you have and construct such an $H$

As $A$ is diagonalizable, it is similar to its transpose $A^T$ via a symmetric positive definite matrix $P$, so $A^T = PAP^{-1}$ therefore $A^TP = PA$.
(If $A = S^{-1}DS$, then $A^T = S^TD(S^{-1})^{T} = S^T(SAS^{-1})(S^{-1})^{T} = (S^TS)A(S^TS)^{-1}$, so $P = S^TS$ suffices as it is symmetric and positive definite)
Every inner product of $\mathbb{R}^n$ can be represented by $\langle x,y \rangle = x^T M y$, where $M$ is a symmetric positive definite matrix.
Therefore $\langle x,y \rangle = x^T Py$ is an inner product and
$\langle Ax,y \rangle = (Ax)^TPy = (x^TA^T)Py = x^T(A^TP)y = x^T(PA)y=x^TP(Ay) = \langle x,Ay \rangle$.
